# How to find Joint Histogram and Marginal Histogram in image processing and what is significance difference between them?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

I'm currently learning Computer Vision and Image processing, in the image processing part there is concept called Image Representations through histogram and further, it is classified into two that is Joint Histogram and Marginal Histogram.

I don't understand how these Joint and Marginal Histograms work and what is significant difference between two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a joint histogram and a marginal histogram in image processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874812/what-is-a-joint-histogram-and-a-marginal-histogram-in-image-processing)

Comment: Google is your friend. I searched for “joint histogram” and the above duplicate came up as 3rd result. There are many more search results there for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried but not been able to understand in detail.

Comment: Then instead of posting a duplicate question, write the question to highlight your understanding and the exact bits you don’t understand. As it is currently written, your question is already answered in the duplicate. Please [edit] your question to make it distinct.