# Histogram comparison between two images

Tags: python, histogram, opencv

I am new to Histogram comparisons.

This code uses these images to make a histogram comparison. The result was impressive with a 0.99 %, however I think that the result resulted in 99% because of the background color. Can someone tell me how can I ignore the white color and compare the actual fruit.

The following code was found [here](https://theailearner.com/2019/08/13/comparing-histograms-using-opencv-python/).

```
# Load the images
img1 = cv2.imread('D:/downloads/app1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('D:/downloads/app2.jpg')

# Convert it to HSV
img1_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img2_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Calculate the histogram and normalize it
hist_img1 = cv2.calcHist([img1_hsv], [0,1], None, [180,256], [0,180,0,256])
cv2.normalize(hist_img1, hist_img1, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
hist_img2 = cv2.calcHist([img2_hsv], [0,1], None, [180,256], [0,180,0,256])
cv2.normalize(hist_img2, hist_img2, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX);

# find the metric value
metric_val = cv2.compareHist(hist_img1, hist_img2, cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA)
```

[image: Apple2]

[image: Apples1]

Comment: Use a mask image in cv2.calcHist() so that it does not count the white pixels. You can make the mask by thresholding your images. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d

Comment: Note that in HSV colorspace white and black and all grays are the same hue as red. You might have produced better results in BGR or some other colorspace such as LAB. But the mask will help no matter which colorspace you use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using some mask as Fred suggested seems to be the cleanest solution, but Fred's comment regarding the HSV color space is even more important here! But, first of all, the reported metric value of `0.99...` (also in the linked article) was obtained using `cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL`, not using `cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA`!

Now, let's stick to OpenCV's common BGR color space, and adapt the code:

```py
import cv2

# Load the images
img1 = cv2.imread('app1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('app2.png')

# Calculate the histograms, and normalize them
hist_img1 = cv2.calcHist([img1], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
cv2.normalize(hist_img1, hist_img1, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
hist_img2 = cv2.calcHist([img2], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
cv2.normalize(hist_img2, hist_img2, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# Find the metric value
metric_val = cv2.compareHist(hist_img1, hist_img2, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
print(metric_val)
# 0.9995753648895891
```

The metric value is still something at 99.9 %.

So, now, let's ignore all white pixels by manually setting `hist_imgx[255, 255, 255] = 0`:

```py
import cv2

# Load the images
img1 = cv2.imread('app1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('app2.png')

# Calculate the histograms, set bin for (255, 255, 255) to 0, and normalize them
hist_img1 = cv2.calcHist([img1], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
hist_img1[255, 255, 255] = 0
cv2.normalize(hist_img1, hist_img1, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
hist_img2 = cv2.calcHist([img2], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
hist_img2[255, 255, 255] = 0
cv2.normalize(hist_img2, hist_img2, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# Find the metric value
metric_val = cv2.compareHist(hist_img1, hist_img2, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
print(metric_val)
# 0.6199666001215806
```

And, the metric value drops to 62 %!

So, your assumption seems to be correct, the white background distorts the whole histogram comparison.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Perfect! What I was looking for :). It was a little bit strange that it resulted in 99% and that's why I wanted to test this without the white background.

Comment: Just a quick question. Can you plt.plot those histograms?

Comment: You get a NumPy array with dimensions `[256, 256, 256]`, since you have some [joint histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55874812/11089932) for all three channels. I could think of 3-dimensional, color coded "plots", maybe scatter plot. If you have three single plots on your mind, you'd need to calculate the three marginal histograms for each channel.

Comment: @HansHirse Setting the white count to zero is an even simpler approach than masking. Nice!

Comment: Please forget, what I said about 3-dimensional plots. You'd need some viewer for 3-dimensional, volumetric data here - best, where you can scroll through all three axes, like those DICOM viewers for CT or MRI scans.

Comment: @HansHirse Sorry for mentioning you again. But I am in need to plot a histogram for this answer and I cannot find a way how to plot it. Do you have any answer to plot this as a histogram ?

Comment: The resulting joint histogram is some kind of 3D volume. A marginal histogram, which you commonly find being plotted, is a 1D signal. You can create three single, marginal histograms for each color channel. You'll see the difference there, too, but it's totally not the same as the above joint histogram! So, NO, there's NO way to plot this joint histogram as a marginal (i.e. common) histogram.

Comment: I need to do the same with C++, can someone provide the code in c++? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You'll only need to raise the minimum saturation value for an HSV mask to effectively mask away all the white background:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_masked(img):
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower = np.array([0, 50, 0])
    upper = np.array([179, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
    return cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

img1 = cv2.imread("apple1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("apple2.png")

cv2.imshow("Apple 1", get_masked(img1))
cv2.imshow("Apple 2", get_masked(img2))

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]
[image]